# Mongoose Insert Many Heap Out of Memory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run a mongoose insert many command with an array that contains about 145,000 JSON objects. I ran this command locally on my mac test environment and it doesn't crash however, when i run it on my dev Windows environment it does.

I have tried to run the "node max-old-space=6086 app.js" command and it works great on my mac (no crash) but crashes on my Windows 2016 machines with the SAME array of objects. Is this a Windows problem?

Also i replaced the sensitive values below with the word "something" to not reveal what my application is doing.

```
const folder = "./monthly/"
const output = []
var count = 0;
const csvFilePath = folder + req.body.fileName

csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  res.send({success: false, message: err.message})
})
.then((jsonObj) => {

  jsonObj.forEach(function(value) {

    var originalDate = new Date(value['something'])
    var something= new Date(originalDate.setMonth(originalDate.getMonth() + 2));

    const body = new Report ({
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: value['something'],
      something: something.toLocaleDateString(),
      something: req.decoded.something
    })

    output.push(body);


  })

  //Everything up until this point runs perfectly 
  //This is where it crashes 
  Report.insertMany(output, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.send({success: false, message: err.message})
    } else {
      console.log(results);
      res.send({success: true, message: "Report Submitted"})
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out the difference between the window/mac environment, or are you trying to update the script so that it doesn't run into that out-of-memory issue?

Comment: Trying to figure out why its crashing regardless of environment. I only highlighted the environment because the same data is crashing one system and not the other.

Comment: If I had to wager, I bet if you reduced the amount of memory that you're providing on your mac, you could probably get it to crash there too. For importing large amounts of data into mongo, you generally either want to use smaller batches (say 1000 items or so) or use `mongoimport`.

Comment: im not sure how to batch out an array of objects and i don't think mongoimport is best because i want to stay within the node app and the mongoose framework

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks for the clarifications. I added an answer with a batching example with async/await. It's a little more complex with promises or callbacks -- I'd recommend using Bluebird (for promises) of caolan's async library (for callbacks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with mongoose and node, you'll want to start batching up objects into smaller inserts. Using `async/await` it might look something like:

```
let toInsert = [];
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  toInsert.push(new Report(item...));
  const isLastItem = i === items.length - 1;
  // every 100 items, insert into the database
  if (i % 100 === 0 || isLastItem) {
    await Report.insertMany(toInsert);
    toInsert = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this when i run your example FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory

Comment: Thank you @willis this is how i took your guidance and made it work. 
async function upload() {
        let toInsert = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
          toInsert.push(new Report(output[i]));
          const isLastItem = i === output.length - 1;
          // every 100 items, insert into the database
          if (i % 100 === 0 || isLastItem) {
            await Report.insertMany(toInsert);
            console.log(toInsert)
            toInsert = [];
          }
        }
      }

      upload();

Comment: Why not `.slice` the array?